# Zenity - transferring data collected from zenity forms to txt Database

Tags: database, bash

Currently I am doing a project and I am stuck. It will be helpful if anyone could help me with it. I am using Linux - Ubuntu system. I using Zenity as my GUI for the book inventory system i am creating. The problem i facing now is i do not know how to transfer the data collected via Zenity --forms to the BookDB.txt .

===================================================================

```
 zenity --forms --title="New book" --text="Add new book" \

   --add-entry="Title" \
   --add-entry="Author" \
   --add-entry="Price" \
   --add-entry="Quantity Available" \
   --add-entry="Quantity sold"  


    read title
    read author
    read price
    read QtyA 
    read QtyS


echo $title:$author:$price:$available:$sold >> BookDB.txt

echo $BookDB "New book title ' $title ' added successfully "
```

===================================================================

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you attempt this yourself? If there are errors, please include them in your question as well. But this being a school assignment, you'd want to do it yourself as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 3):

zenity outputs to stdout. With a form, the fields are separated, by default, with a pipe. You'll want to do this:

```
data=$(
    zenity --forms --title="New book" --text="Add new book" \
       --add-entry="Title" \
       --add-entry="Author" \
       --add-entry="Price" \
       --add-entry="Quantity Available" \
       --add-entry="Quantity sold"  
)
case $? in
     1) echo "you cancelled"; exit 1 ;;
    -1) echo "some error occurred"; exit -1 ;;
     0) IFS="|" read -r title author price qtyA qtyS <<< "$data" ;;
esac
```

If you're not comfortable using pipe as the output separator, there's a `--separator` option. For example, you might want to use the "FS" character: `--separator=$'\034'`, then `IFS=$'\034' read -r a b c d e <<<"$data"`

I'm finding the documentation for zenity pretty slim, but here's the official manual: https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/

Comment: A pretty good explanation based on the slim references. That's the only downside to `zenity`, `kdialog`, `dialog`, etc..., data extraction based on the form return is sometimes a bit strained.